# How to compare columns from different files and replace the value in one column?

Tags: linux, awk

I have two files:

input1

```
22 rs145072688 14431347  C  G 0.3418 0.648 0.830 0.516 0.506 0.497 0.785 0.586
22   rs201725126 14432618  G  A 0.8119 1.571 1.748 1.661 1.384 1.374 1.614 1.718
22   rs200579949 14433624  G  A 0.8598 1.590 1.669 1.763 1.754 1.832 1.627 1.250
22   rs75454623 14433659  C  A 0.7888 1.564 1.606 1.667 1.355 1.619 1.692 1.775
22   rs199856693 14433758  G  A 0.9354 1.807 1.936 1.906 1.847 1.929 1.734 1.327
22  rs9604721 14434713  C  T 0.9723 1.984 1.984 1.984 1.984 1.984 1.878 1.412
```

input2

```
rs145072688:10352:T:TA rs145072688
rs201725126:13116:T:G rs201725126
rs200579949:13118:A:G rs200579949
rs75454623:14930:A:G rs75454623
rs199856693:14933:G:A rs199856693
```

desired output:

```
22 rs145072688:10352:T:TA 14431347  C  G 0.3418 0.648 0.830 0.516 0.506 0.497 0.785 0.586
22   rs201725126:13116:T:G 14432618  G  A 0.8119 1.571 1.748 1.661 1.384 1.374 1.614 1.718
22   rs200579949:13118:A:G 14433624  G  A 0.8598 1.590 1.669 1.763 1.754 1.832 1.627 1.250
22   rs75454623:14930:A:G 14433659  C  A 0.7888 1.564 1.606 1.667 1.355 1.619 1.692 1.775
22   rs199856693:14933:G:A 14433758  G  A 0.9354 1.807 1.936 1.906 1.847 1.929 1.734 1.327
22  rs9604721 14434713  C  T 0.9723 1.984 1.984 1.984 1.984 1.984 1.878 1.412
```

So if the 2nd columns of both files match I want to replace the values in 2nd column in file input1 with values in 1st column from input2.

I tried this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} $2 in a{$2=a[$1]}1' input2 input1
```

and this

```
awk 'FNR==NR { F2[$2]=$2 ; next } $2 in F2 {$1 = F2[$1] ; print } ' input2 input1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first attempt is almost right.

```
awk '
    FNR==NR { a[$2]=$1; next }
    $2 in a { $2=a[$2] }
    1
' input2 input1
```

- `$2 in a` looks for $2 in the keys of a, not in its values
- so store column 2 as value rather than the key for `a`
- in the second line action, you should refer to the second column (of input1) not first column (of input2)